# How to read UDH of a SmsMessage?

Tags: android

Is there a way to read the UDH of a SmsMessage with Android?

`SmsMessageBase` class from the source, but it is said that it is just available during debug and framework layer?

There is also a `SmsHeader` however I am not sure how to access it from `SmsMessage`

Comment: Possible duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5678952/retreive-sms-with-user-data-header-udh-on-android-devices

Comment: Zakaria, that question which you pointed to is not answered and it's not quite a duplicate